# How do I expose ports on Heroku with a Dockerfile?

Tags: heroku, docker

I am trying to deploy a Docker image on Heroku and am trying to understand how to expose multiple ports.  Here is the Docker command that I am trying to run in the Heroku deploy:

```
docker run \
    -p 2222:22 \
    -p 33306:3306 \
    -p 27017:27017 \
    -p 28015:28015 \
    -p 29015:29015 \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    test/db-migration
```

How do I do this in Heroku?

Comment: That's the ways to do that. Did you have any error?

Comment: I don't have any errors, but I didn't think Heroku allowed you to expose specific ports.  Doesn't it assign the ports for you?  As when I am exposing a port in a Node app, we access it with `process.env.PORT`.

Answer (score 22):

You can't - you should use the $PORT environment variable which will be randomly assigned and then mapped to port 80 by the Heroku routers. Also, only http requests are accepted. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime for more details.

Comment: So how do you create multiple `PORT`'s?

Comment: you can't - it's the same as a buildpack deployment - the Heroku router accepts requests on ports 443/80 and then proxies the request to your app in its randomly assigned port number. An app only gets 1 $PORT assigned to it.

Comment: John Beynon is correct. you can't do this on heroku. you only get the `$PORT` env var, and that's it.

Comment: So I have multiple db's in this one container.  I assume that if I am going to use Heroku, I will need to create multiple apps which each expose a single `PORT` instead of 1 app that exposes multiple `PORT`s

Comment: only http requests are accepted by the router - you wouldn't be able to communicate across apps...you should use a Heroku Postgres DB or one via an addon.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Dockhero](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/dockhero) add-on. It's a good way to deploy supplementary resources alongside your Heroku app, and it supports docker-compose with multi-port mapping. The web app itself should still be running on Heroku dynos.