# Docker PHP + Apache deployment on Heroku crashes

Tags: php, apache, docker, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a docker container and although I have tried several options, it always crashes. On local in works fine, on port 8080.

Right now, I am using PHP + Apache.

My folder herarchy looks like this:

```
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile 
www
   .htaccess
   index.php
```

My Dockerfile is this one:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
COPY www /var/www/html
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
RUN service apache2 restart
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

My docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: myproject
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

And the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

When I check the Heroku logs (heroku logs --tail), this is what I see:

```
Starting process with command `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`
State changed from starting to crashed
Process exited with status 1
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently solved this issue myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452086/deploy-a-dockerized-laravel-app-using-apache-on-heroku/54469924#54469924) in case you ever want to try Heroku again :)

Essentially, I used the Docker `CMD` statement to change the apache port configs at runtime.

```
CMD sed -i "s/80/$PORT/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf && docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground
```

Comment: You can also use `${PORT}` inside the `000-default.conf` and `ports.conf` files. eg `Listen ${PORT}`

Comment: Are you still using this setup? It looks like it stopped working. I'm getting: `apache2: Syntax error on line 150 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/ports.conf: Permission denied`

Comment: Also stoppen working for me. See my new answer below @DamianPaszkowski

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer by @caleb-gray stopped working in September 2019 for me but I came up with an alternative solution:

Instead of replacing the port values in the Dockerfile I replaced them in the original apache2 .conf files with the env variables and then copied them over to the Docker image. That also means the .conf files are now part of my repository (I copied them from the running Docker container).

My folder hierarchy:

```
Dockerfile
apache-config/
  ports.conf
  000-default.conf
```

For example in my ports.conf the line

```
Listen 80
```

is changed to

```
Listen ${PORT}
```

And in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./apache-config/ports.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf                                
COPY ./apache-config/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf    
CMD docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground
```

Works fine so far

Answer (score 2):

Answer is simple, you can't bind to a specific port you should use $PORT env variable. More about this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548074/how-do-i-expose-ports-on-heroku-with-a-dockerfile).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.
I have been trying different options, with no luck. 
I removed:
EXPOSE 80
and added: 
ENV PORT "$PORT"
EXPOSE ${PORT}
but heroku still tells me the same error. :(

Comment: I finally opted o go with Google Cloud. Everything worked like a charm.