# Deploy a Dockerized Laravel app using Apache on Heroku

Tags: laravel, apache, docker, heroku, port

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel 5.5 app using Docker on Heroku. I'm coming up against the problem where Heroku dynamically assigns the $PORT value though, and I can't figure out where to tell Apache to use $PORT instead of port 80. Has anyone else had success deploying an app using Apache in Docker to Heroku with the $PORT specification?

To be specific, this is the error I get tailing the Heroku logs:

```
2019-01-31T14:01:17.605297+00:00 app[web.1]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

which I understand to mean that the container is trying to listen on Port 80, but the host is using $PORT instead of 80.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.5-apache

#install all the system dependencies and enable PHP modules 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libicu-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  git \
  zip \
  unzip \
  && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
  && docker-php-ext-install \
  intl \
  mbstring \
  mcrypt \
  pcntl \
  pdo_mysql \
  pdo_pgsql \
  pgsql \
  zip \
  opcache

ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 3.0.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
  && curl -L https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz | tar xvz -C /usr/src/php/ext/redis --strip 1 \
  && echo 'redis' >> /usr/src/php-available-exts \
  && docker-php-ext-install redis

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

#set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

#change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

#change the web_root to laravel /var/www/html/public folder
RUN sed -i -e "s/html/html\/public/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# enable apache module rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

#copy source files and run composer
COPY . $APP_HOME

# install all PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction

#change ownership of our applications
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data $APP_HOME
```

And here's my Heroku Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

And here's my heroku.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Thanks!

Comment: What command and parameters do you use to start your container? The public port of docker containers is where the Heroku port comes in. Internal ports that may be defined in a Dockerfile are not relevant.

Comment: @Namoshek it's my understanding that Heroku uses the command in the Procfile to run the container. I've updated my post with my heroku.yml to show that I'm not using any run config, which should default to the Procfile as per the end of the first paragraph [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#run-defining-the-processes-to-run)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

Using [this SO post](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/94#issuecomment-320695125), I discovered I could insert a `CMD` statement at the end of my Dockerfile to `sed` replace the ports in my apache config files to the magical `$PORT` environment variable at run time.

New Dockerfile below:

```
#start with our base image (the foundation) - version 7.1.5
FROM php:7.1.5-apache

#install all the system dependencies and enable PHP modules 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libicu-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  git \
  zip \
  unzip \
  && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
  && docker-php-ext-install \
  intl \
  mbstring \
  mcrypt \
  pcntl \
  pdo_mysql \
  pdo_pgsql \
  pgsql \
  zip \
  opcache

ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 3.0.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
  && curl -L https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz | tar xvz -C /usr/src/php/ext/redis --strip 1 \
  && echo 'redis' >> /usr/src/php-available-exts \
  && docker-php-ext-install redis

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

#set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

#change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

#change the web_root to laravel /var/www/html/public folder
RUN sed -i -e "s/html/html\/public/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# enable apache module rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

#copy source files and run composer
COPY . $APP_HOME

# install all PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction

#change ownership of our applications
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data $APP_HOME

#update apache port at runtime for Heroku
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD sed -i "s/80/$PORT/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf && docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground
```