# Heroku PHP & Apache dyno crash with error H10

Tags: php, apache, docker, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Dockerfile from Windows to Heroku however the Heroku Dyno keeps crashing with error code: H10, the Dockerfile works fine locally.

```
2020-04-13T22:25:09.749176+00:00 app[web.1]: AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
2020-04-13T22:26:40.155292+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=***.herokuapp.com request_id=*** fwd="***" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

ENV PORT 3000

CMD sed -i "s/80/$PORT/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf && docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground

COPY src /var/www/html/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

I am using the Heroku CLI with the following:
`heroku create`
`heroku container:push web`
`heroku container:release web`

I have found many articles stating this is probably a port issue:
[Docker PHP + Apache deployment on Heroku crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884647/docker-php-apache-deployment-on-heroku-crashes)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7):

So after hours of testing I finally found the answer, it appears to be an issue with Heroku & Docker:
https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/293

Also helpful:
https://www.rickpeyton.com/programming/deploy-wordpress-to-heroku-with-docker/

Luckily there is a quick fix, be sure to restart your Dyno after:

```
heroku labs:enable --app=YOUR-APP runtime-new-layer-extract
```

I hope this saves someone time.