# Heroku is not getting PORT for react package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

In my local server, I am able to use react on the front for PORT 8001 on my express app.

It shows on localhost:8001, and the express app works well.

I need a way for **heroku** to do the same thing. Currently, I get

> Cannot GET /

Express is using the server 8000, and react is using 8001. (i cannot put the same on both ports because of api conflicts)

So it has to be on separate ports.

Like could it be

https://murmuring-brushlands-80878:8001.herokuapp.com or something?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "superagent": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    // PORT 8001
    "start": "PORT=8001 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

**express package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sequelize-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "cd ./client && npm start ",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others  \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "foreman": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.11",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
var postRoute  = require('./routes/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') ;
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
var models = require('./models/');
const host = '0.0.0.0';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
// const allowOrigin = process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*'
// CORS Middleware
if (!process.env.PORT) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

// console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
if (!process.env.PORT) {
  console.log('[api][port] 8000 set as default')
  console.log('[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * set as default')
} else {
  console.log('[api][node] Loaded ENV vars from .env file')
  console.log(`[api][port] ${process.env.PORT}`)
  console.log(`[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN}`)
}
require('./config/passport-github');
require('./config/passport');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret : process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 84,
  resave: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false})); 
const isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    next();
    console.log('this works');
  }else{
   res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/signIn');
  }
}
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
//   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',  true);
//   res.header("preflightContinue", false)
//   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
//   next();
// });
app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that React is sending to the API
    'exposedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that you are sending back to React
    'origin': '*',
    'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    'preflightContinue': false
}));
app.use('/api/users', userRoute );
app.use('/api/posts', isAuthenticated,  postRoute );
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  // req.session.user = user
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});

app.listen(PORT, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Heroku only exposes port 80/443 (and does some internal rerouting of requests to whichever port the app is really running on). [You can't expose multiple ports from a Heroku instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44548327/11322443)

I'm assuming this Heroku instance would be a production environment rather than a development one. If that's the case, what the best practice would be is to `npm build` the React app for production and have your Express server [serve the static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) with your server, then prepend all your endpoints with something like `/api/`.

Comment: ill accept as answer but this is extremely confusing. I don't know where to start

Comment: Sorry about that, where I would start is to build the client somewhere into the server folder, like `public`. Then go through the "serve static files" link to serve everything in that folder. You would no longer need to deal with ports, in React, you would send requests to `/api/users` and in your server you would redirect to `/signin`.

Comment: https://github.com/EliHood/mysequelizereact, if you want to take a better look. You think i should use the target: api method thing for the api

Comment: im taking a look at this too
https://medium.com/quick-code/deploying-production-build-of-react-app-to-heroku-2548d8bf6936

Comment: im still confused man. I just want to get express + react on heroku :'(

Comment: This might also be a good resource https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250

Comment: thank link helped got it working. Now i can focus on getting the sequlize working