# How can I use the assigned port in an application on Heroku?

Tags: php, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm building an application with 3 containers:

- NodeJS for the frontend
- PHP for the API
- PostgreSQL as the database

I'm deploying them as 3 docker images in the Heroku Container Registry, how can I acquire the ports that Heroku gives me for every app at runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expose ports on Heroku with a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548074/how-do-i-expose-ports-on-heroku-with-a-dockerfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but there's no great answer to this question.

As far as I know, heroku gives port at runtime via `$PORT` variable.

Just read the following question which seems to be the same as yours:

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548074/how-do-i-expose-ports-on-heroku-with-a-dockerfile)