# node js docker is not running on heroku

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku

Node js project in Docker container is not running on Heroku.

Here is the source code.

**Docker file**

```
FROM node:14    
WORKDIR /home/tor/Desktop/work/docker/speech-analysis/build
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

**server.js**

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.port||8080;
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(PORT);
console.log("Running on http://:${PORT}");
```

Comment: Can you please explain more details? Like what is the part thats not running? If you're getting errors, share outputs with us.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to expose anything when having a container for Heroku. It takes care of it automatically. If you are running the same Docker locally, you can do:

```
docker build -t myapp:latest .
docker run -e PORT=8080 -p 8080:8080 -t myapp:latest
```

2. I think that the environment variables are case-sensitive on Linux systems - so you need to change the

```
const PORT = process.env.port||8080;
```

... to:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT||8080;
```

... as Heroku sets an environment variable `PORT` (and not `port`).

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44548327/3957754) you just need to use the port 80 in your expose or inside of nodejs:

```
app.listen(80)
```

Heroku at run, will generate a random port and bind it to 80

```
docker run ... -p 46574:80 ...
```

So if your nodejs app is running at port 80 inside of container, everything will be fine